# How to use https on one page only?

Tags: redirect, htaccess, https, http

Shortly: I want my WordPress to respond in **https** on exactly one specifc route. Everything else should respond in **http**. Is that even possible in WordPress and how to do it?

## Details

I have a single route in my WordPress site that I want to reply in **https** because it's used as an endpoint when receiving payment notifications from gateways.

Everything else **must** keep responding in **http**.

I assumed it was easy, I created two virtual hosts in my webserver with some redirect rules:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    (...)
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    (...)
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/my/endpoint/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]        
</VirtualHost>
```

The rules are tested and correct. They basically means: in the HTTPS site, redirect everything except a given route to HTTP.

Still, when WordPress index.php page takes control, another redirect happens and I'm back to the home page of the http site. Tested with DevTools and preserving logs.

I tested with different WordPress site and my guess is that the problem is what happens in the .htaccess, where everything which is not an actual file or directory gets redirected to `index.php` which in turns is redirected to HTTP.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thank you for any hint.

Comment: Your problem is most likely with canonical urls. just keep in mind that https on one page only is sometimes not enough to make relevant information encrypted

Comment: Can't you just use http plugin and specify which page you want http forced on?

Comment: @MarkKaplun thank you for your reply, I am aware of what I am trying to do, I am focusing on why it does not work - then we can discuss if it's a good idea or not. I don't think canonical URLs have anything to do with it, but maybe if you expand your explanation I may have a look.

Comment: @YobdDigital I will have a look at the Https plugin, thank you.